# Dynamic TemplateUrl path with angular JS 4

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {CommonService} from './../../shared';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-layout',       
  templateUrl: 'thmes'+THEME+'./main-layout.component.html',      
  styleUrls: ['./main-layout.component.scss']    
})

export class MainLayoutComponent implements OnInit {    

  constructor(private common: CommonService) { }         
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.common.getTheme());       
  }

}
```

i want to render files like above. i checked dynamic module rendering also. its also taking only path and not allowing dynamic strings it. how can i acheive appoach like above,

i have seen this approach was there in angular 1 through functions, how can i achieve this in typescript

Answer (score 0):

Does `THEME` change in run-time e.g. via query parameter or require to change during transpilation level only?

If later may be you can define it via WebPack's DefinePlugin. But in the case if former I don't think you can do it unless via child routes.

Comment: this THEME param will come from first API call, will get theme name via response.